# How to figure out the Android device from user-agent string (4.x versions)

Tags: javascript, android, ruby, browser

Android device is a part of a user-agent string:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.4; en-gb; GT-I9100 Build/IMM76D) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30

Opera/9.80 (Android 4.0.3; Linux; Opera Mobi/ADR-1212030829) Presto/2.11.355 Version/12.10

Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.1; en-us; SAMSUNG-SGH-I317 Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30
```

However, the device might reside in different indexes, when splitting the string by `;` (and sometimes it just isn't there). Is there an easy way to fetch the **device name** out in Javascript/Ruby?

**Update:** just to clarify: I am interested to fetch a device name, not an Android/version

Comment: Didi you find out the solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't there, there's no way to get it is there.. If it is in the form of "Android x.y.z;", regular expressions are your friend

assuming "user_agent" contains the user-agent string:

Ruby, e.g.

```
user_agent[/Android (.*?);/]
```

Variable $1 will contain the version.

Javascript

```
var version = user_agent.match("Android (.*?);")[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a way to know whether it is an Android device or not, the Javascript code may be as simple as:

```
function isAndroid() {
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    return (ua.indexOf("android") > -1);
}
```

If you are interested in version too, try this Javascript code:

```
function getAndroidVersion() {
    var androidVersion = -1; // def value, for non-Android devices
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var androidIndex = ua.indexOf('android');

    if(androidIndex != -1) {
        var versionStartIndex = androidIndex + 8;
        var versionEndIndex = ua.indexOf(';', versionStartIndex);

        androidVersion = parseFloat(ua.slice(versionStartIndex, versionEndIndex));
    }

    return androidVersion;
}
```